# n-digit Pattern Matching in Lua

Tags: lua, pattern-matching

I'm new to Lua.

Say i have a string "1234567890".

I want to iterate over all possible 3 digit numbers. (ie `123,234,345,456....`)

```
for m in string.gmatch("1234567890","%d%d%d") do
      print (m)
end
```

But this gives me the output `123,456,789`.

What kind of Pattern should i be using?

And secondly, a related question, how do i specify a `3-digit` number? `"%3d"` doesn't seem to work. Is `"%d%d%d"` the only way?

*Note:* This isn't tagged `Regular expression`because Lua doesn't have RegExp. (atleast natively)

Thanks in advance :)

**Update:** As Amber Points out, there is no "overlapping" matches in Lua. And, about the second query, i'm now stuck using `string.rep("%d",n)` since Lua doesn't support fixed number of repeats.

Comment: `("%d"):rep(n)` is a slightly more idiomatic way to write the call to `string.rep`. It works because `string` is the metatable for all string values by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gmatch` never returns overlapping matches (and `gsub` never replaces overlapping matches, fwiw).

Your best bet would probably be to iterate through all possible length-3 substrings, check each to see if they match the pattern for a 3-digit number, and if so, operate on them.

(And yes, `%d%d%d` is the only way to write it. Lua's abbreviated patterns support doesn't have a fixed-number-of-repetitions syntax.)

Comment: Thank you, That's unfortunate! Do you have any idea about a simpler n-digit pattern? :)

Comment: Hey, as I edited my answer to mention, Lua's simplistic pattern matching doesn't have a simpler syntax.

Comment: I've already done that...:) but i thought maybe i should go for a more "Lua-ish" Solution. :)

Answer (score 5):

You are correct that core Lua does not include full regular expressions. The patterns understood by the `string` module are simpler, but sufficient for a lot of cases. Matching overlapping n-digit numbers, unfortunately, isn't one of them.

That said, you can manually iterate over the string's length and attempt the match at each position since the `string.match` function takes a starting index. For example:

```
s = "1234567890"
for i=1,#s do
    m = s:match("%d%d%d", i)
    if m then print(m) end
end
```

This produces the following output:

```
C:>Lua
Lua 5.1.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2008 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> s = "1234567890"
> for i=1,#s do
>>     m = s:match("%d%d%d", i)
>>     if m then print(m) end
>> end
123
234
345
456
567
678
789
890
>
```